# How to avoid using the Web context in axios.get

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I'm running a backend service which returns some data at this address: http://localhost:8080/vuejs-demo/rest/customers 
Then I have an index.html page available at: http://localhost:8080/vuejs-demo/index.html which fetches data from the REST Service:

```
listUsers: function() {
    axios.get("/vuejs-demo/rest/customers", {

        })
        .then(response => {
            this.users = response.data
        })
}
```

The thing is, I don't want to hardcode the root Web context information "**vuejs-demo**".
Since both the index.html page and the REST Service are under the "vuejs-demo" Web context I assume I can call directly the "rest/customers" endpoint.
However using:

```
    axios.get("rest/customers", {

        })
        .then(response => {
            this.users = response.data
        })
}
```

Fails to include the Web context, resulting in http://localhost:8080//vuejs-demo/rest/customers
Same using  "/rest/customers" it results in  http://localhost:8080/rest/customers which also causes a 404 error.
Is there any way to get around this issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After importing axios you can [set some defaults](https://github.com/axios/axios#global-axios-defaults), one of them being a base url:

```
import axios from 'axios'
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:8080/vuejs-demo/rest';
```